# Download all images at distance 2 using Mac OS X

Tags: macos, download, wget, download-manager, file-download

I need to download all the images from a website on my computer. The images are not listed all in one page. Instead I have an index page that links a set of pages (`page1.html`, `page2.html`, ...) each with many images inside.

DownThemAll of Firefox only downloads the images from a single page.

There is no `wget`, but still I understand it would download the images from one page. In a sense I need the images at distance 2. Linked to a link from a page.

Comment: Why not ask the creator/owner of that website to mail them you you? Or to put them in an archive ?

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no wget"?

Comment: Their website is really badly done. I don't think they invest any time in it. So the only way to look through those pictures is offline.

Comment: mac osx does not have wget. I would have to install it

Comment: Would that be an issue for you? This is the tool for that job.

Comment: ok, but how do I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install `wget` on OS X through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).*

Then, it's as simple as:

```
wget -nd -A jpg,gif -r http://example.com
```

- The [`-nd` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Directory-Options.html) does not create a directory for each path segment.
- [`-A` sets the file types](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Types-of-Files.html) allowed.
- `-r` crawls recursively.
- You can add `-l 2` (or similar) to restrict it to two [levels of recursion](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download).

<sub>* If this is too complicated for you. alternatively there's a 2008 [blog with a prebuilt version](http://www.statusq.org/archives/2008/07/30/1954/), but it might not work in all cases.</sub>

Comment: thanks. Installed with brew, and works like a chasm. I also learned about a really important tool. :-)